# Multiple insert in mysql table, some of which may be repeated

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I'm developing a php script in which I insert multiple data into a mysql table, but some of this data may already be inserted. I can try to insert each of the individual data and detect the #1062 error (duplicate entry), but it would be very inefficient since it can be more than 100 entries. So, is there any way to do this in one query or must I use a query for each entry to be inserted?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE command to accomplish this.  In the "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" section, you can just do some kind of update that changes nothing.  For example, "SET fieldName=fieldName", just so nothing is actually changed.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html